# WSO2 Identity Server SignatureAlgorithm

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

is it possible to change the Signature-Algorithm in WSO2 API-Manger / Identity Server for the JWT-Token.
I'm using WSO2 API-Manager 2.0.0.
I found in the directory `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml` on line 229 the XML-Node

```
<SignatureAlgorithm>SHA256withRSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
```

But I can't finde a list with accepted values. I want to use the HS256-HMAC instead of SHA256withRSA. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the only signature algorithm that's currently supported. See [the code](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/AbstractJWTGenerator.java#L453:L464).

But you can write your own JWT generator implementation [like this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/token/JWTGenerator.java) extending `AbstractJWTGenerator`.